# Find duplicate records in exist database table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, duplicates

I'm new to databases. I want to find the Duplicate records from the database table which is already created i.e. i m not concern about to prevent duplicate insertion but i wanted to know the duplicate records.
i tried with

```
 Distinct
```

key word but it will show the records by removing duplicate data,
and after that i tried

```
unique index
```

which will say the the table name which are having duplicate records but not show or give duplicate records.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide table structure in your question? Thx in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List the columns that make a record a duplicate and then group by them and count the occourances

```
select col1. col2
from your_table
group by col1, col2
having count(*) > 1
```

The `having` clause lists only those having more than one enry in the table.

Comment: thanks for the solution it worked, but i m running sqlite3 commands using connectionC API, is their any way to get all those duplicate data into file. here its only displaying the records.